# Exclude a category id from category collection in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to fetch all the sub categories added via admin side of magento. From the categories fetched I would like to exclude one category id. Below provided is the code which I have used to fetch all the sub category

```
<?php
      $allCategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                       ->getCollection()
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                       ->addAttributeToFilter('level',2)
                       ->addIsActiveFilter(); 
?>
```

Please let me know to exclude category id 69 and display all other category of level 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the bellow code,

```
<?php
      $allCategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                       ->getCollection()
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                       ->addAttributeToFilter('level',2)
                       ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => 69))
                       ->addIsActiveFilter(); 

?>
```

Let me know if you have any query

Thanks